# How are gatsby, react-static, netlify, netlify cms, and contentful related or used together?

Tags: reactjs, static, gatsby, react-static

I'm trying to learn more about static sites and the various tools around them.

So I think:

- Gatsby and React-Static are tools/way of taking JSON data and making
  a static fast loading site. Something that can be uploaded right into
  s3 or a cloud storage bucket and will load really fast.

  - I think netlify is just a series of tools built on AWS that make
    managing static sites easily?
  - netlify CMS (I think) is a way to be able to put content into github
    and have it tie into a static site?
  - contentful is a way to take user input/content (similar to a wordpres
    admin) that outputs JSON. It's like a non-technical user way to input
    content and output it in a way developers can consume with things
    like gatsby/react-static

I'm just not really sure how these are related or where there is overlap. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Got an amazing answer from user Ziinc the [react-static spectrum chat][1]

> You're mostly on the right track. Gatsby and react-static are static
>   site generators. By default they're more optimized to load fast (since
>   the starting templates are lightweight), but it is completely possible
>   for poor development skills to make it bloated and slow. both SSGs
>   allow for the pulling in of data from different sources, not just json
>   data during the build step. A static website can be either served from
>   a web host (apache, nginx), or from cloud storage, or even dropbox (i
>   think).
>
> Netlify is a static website hosting service l that allows you to build
>   your website (usually a SSG) from a git service and then be deployed
>   to their content delivery network.
>
> Netlify CMS is netlify's attempt to make it easier for content editors
>   to have a friendly ui to update a git repo (since usually content is
>   placed directly in the git repo, but not always of course). Think of
>   it as a private portion of your website for admins. It is basically a
>   flatfile cms.
>
> contentful is a headless cms that is usually for teams. Headless
>   meaning that there is not online viewing page. it only handles the
>   content storage portion. This allows the decoupling of your content
>   storage and your view layer. they allow a business to outsource the
>   database management and server management to focus on the content.
>   there are many other headless cms options, with a new one popping up
>   everyday. Contentful overlaps with netlify cms at the CMS featureset,
>   but netlifycms is flatfile while contentful has databases and servers
>   hosted for customers.
>
> [1]:
>   https://spectrum.chat/react-static?thread=76bdc0c2-bbfa-460f-a811-8e2fe9008f69

Answer (score 1):

You are correct on all points. The following is also true and may answer / add to the points above:

- Gatsby + Netlify gives you automatic deployment and continuous integration.
- Gatsby + Contentful: seem like a good match, may give this a try https://www.contentful.com/r/knowledgebase/gatsbyjs-and-contentful-in-five-minutes/

I see little overlap but, see them working very well together.